# Why is the Black-Scholes PDE called degenerate

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, finance

I am working in Mathematical Finance and know that the Black-Scholes PDE is degenerate at $x=0$ (I assumed that this was because at 0 the convection and diffusion terms vanish and one is left $V_{t} = rV$).

Is there a more precise way of defining this ?

Secondly, is there a reason that one needs weighted spaces to consider finite element methods other than the fact that the weights arise naturally when deriving the weak formulation?

Comment: Thanks for the accept. I recommend asking your second question in a separate thread on Math.SE. Also, as a general rule of thumb, only ask one question per thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **TLDR**: degenerate is short for *degenerate elliptic*.

Consider a second-order differential operator $$\mathcal{L}u\equiv \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij} u_{ij}+\sum_{i=1}^n b_i u_i + cu$$ where I am using subscripts on $u$ to denote derivatives. In your case, $$\mathcal{L}V\equiv rSV_{S}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}S^{2}V_{SS}-rV.$$ $\mathcal{L}$ is said to be elliptic at a point $x$ if for every nonzero real vector $\xi$, $$\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}(x) u_{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j>0.$$ It is degenerate elliptic at a point $x$ if the above inequality holds with equality.

Lastly, it is worthwhile to mention that *uniform ellipticity* is defined by changing the inequality to $>C$ for some $C>0$ for all points in the domain of interest. Note that the Black-Scholes operator is uniformly elliptic on any $[0,\infty)\setminus B_r(0)$ where $r>0$.

(I do not know the answer to your second question)

Comment: Okay, thank you. But then I assume that when these conditions fail at a point its degenerate?

Comment: I have elaborated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Very Helpful. 

Given that the ellipticity only requires a condition on the coefficient of the second order term (if I understand correctly). Does the fact that the first order terms also vanishes at 0 cause a different kind of degeneracy?

Comment: The ellipticity condition is often used in deriving a maximum principle; the advection terms do not hinder this derivation in any way. I cannot think of a general situation in which the advection terms disappearing would cause hardship, but I can't say for certainty that there isn't one.