# Technical difficulties with degenerate PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, finance, stochastic-differential-equations

<sub>[Crossposted](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/71621) at Quantitative Finance SE</sub>

---

I have seen lot of discussions in this Math. S.E. platform about 'degenerate partial differential equations'. But I still unclear about the 'technical difficulty' with the degeneracy present in the Black-Scholes model governing option pricing. While dealing the generalized Black-Scholes equation
$$\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(S,t)S^2\frac{\partial^2{V}}{\partial{S}^2}+(r(S,t)-D(S,t))S \frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{S}}-r(S,t)V=0,~~~~S\in (0,\infty),~~~t\in(0,T),$$
with the terminal condition $V (S,T)=\max(S-E,0)$, most of the numerical analysts ([Page no: 1767](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S187705091630922X?token=154B2CBB026D8FD4592F900D6AF6E6091456534DDE8903F6DB8B51C9C8BD2C42F8C7ACADE44E93AAB30F51889B3D8237&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20230210041135), [2230](https://www.aimspress.com/fileOther/PDF/Math/math-05-03-147.pdf) ) attempt transforming the price variable $S$ to a dimensionless variable $x=\ln S$, and claim thereby tackled the degeneracy of the model. I feel some trouble should be there near $S=0$ affecting the nature of the PDE. Further, I got the exact definition from the [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1816237/). Is it a matter of the possible domain class of the B-S operator?

Regardless, I am interested to know about the analytical difficulty while dealing with such degenerate PDEs. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I think you should have waited a bit longer before crossposting.  Crossposting without notification was a really bad idea.  I would say you should consider investing some time in proper tagging, so that the most qualified people can find your question.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a problem *per se*. If $S = 0$ then the dynamics of the risky asset vanishes and the solution is just the present value of the payoff.

If anything, it may cause a problem since it changes the nature of the PDE. With the transformation you proposed, the coefficients of the derivatives won't vanish and then the nature won't change either.